# Who could I be?

Tags: riddle

> I am kind, compassionate and cruel
>
> I am just and unfair
>
> I am quick and I am slow
>
> I am known and unknown
>
> I am friend and foe

**Who am I?**

Comment: Rudyard Kipling!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I say the answer is

> Death

I am kind, compassionate and cruel

> For those who are suffering death can be compassionate.  For others it can be cruel

I am just and unfair

> Death can be seen as just for murderers and unfair for good people

I am quick and I am slow

> Some people die suddenly while others suffer slow deaths

I am known and unknown

> People see others die all the time but no one knows what happens after death

I am friend and foe

> Death is a friend to those who are suffering but a foe to those who have a lot of life to live

Comment: And we have our winner!

Answer (score 3):

Possible answer (very meta)

> A riddle

I am just and unfair

> When solving a riddle, everyone approaches the puzzle from a unique perspective based on individual background, this makes it inherently unfair as certain "thinking styles" or creative perspectives are more likely to succeed at riddles. The fact that this perspective-discrimination is essentially random makes it just.

I am quick and I am slow

> Riddle solutions can be arrived at quickly or slowly

I am known and I am unknown

> Some people know the answer (the person posing the riddle) and some people don't (the participants)

I am friend and foe

> A friend can be judged by the net improvement he/she adds to your life. A riddle can be intellectually stimulating like a friend. Sometimes the quest to solve riddle can be all-consuming or overstimulating, resulting it having a negative impact (foe).

Comment: Interesting take :) not the answer I had in mind however

Comment: @user43218 Is it "fire"? It feels appealing.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Thoughts

I am kind, compassionate and cruel

> You can think kind, compassionate or cruel thoughts

I am just and unfair

> Sometimes they are justified and sometimes you can unfairly judge someone

I am quick and I am slow

> Your thoughts can be formed quickly or slowly

I am known and unknown

> Sometimes you don't even know what your thinking about. Another take could be that no one know's what your thoughts on a subject are until you tell then. Then they will know your thoughts.

I am friend and foe

> Your thoughts can lift and build you up: "I can do this!" Or they can bring you down with negativity: "I can't do anything right". This line made me think of the saying "you are your worst enemy".

Comment: This isn't what I had in mind but it does work well

Answer (score 1):

My answer:

> The internet.

I am kind, compassionate and cruel

I am just and unfair

> People online can be kind, cruel, just in judgements, unfair in how they treat you.

I am quick and I am slow

> High speed and low speed internet.

I am known and unknown

> You have user names, but don't know their real identity.

I am friend and foe

> People online can be your friend, or your enemy.

Answer (score 0):

It could be

> JUSTICE

As,

> Justice is equivivocal to both the parties involved and hence can be appearing of opposite qualities at the same time.